# Connecting JMeter to MonogDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, mongodb-atlas

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>cluster0-kjxf3.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Returns `Response message:Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri needs to start with mongodb://`. Above URL example comes from MongoDB Atlas manual, deleting **+srv** causes:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb.net: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Driver Examples](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#driver-examples) documentation section

> To connect to an Atlas M0 (Free Tier) cluster, you must use Java version 8 or greater and use a Java driver version that supports **MongoDB 3.4**. For complete documentation on compatibility between the Java driver and MongoDB, see the [MongoDB compatibility matrix](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java).

So make sure to download [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) version 3.4 or higher and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). You will also need to remove all previous versions of the MongoDB Driver to avoid [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell). JMeter restart will be required to pick up the new .jar and unload old ones (if any)

You may also find [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article useful.